# Is there a bijective function $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that is discontinuous?

Tags: functions

Is there a bijective function that is discontinuous?

Comment: Take a continuous bijection and exchange the images of two random points.

Comment: It would be more interesting to ask for a everywhere discontinuous bijection

Answer (score 14):

Discontinuous everywhere: $f(x)=x$ if $x$ rational, $x+1$ if $x$ irrational.

Comment: To make this an even more fascinating example: If we use $-x$ and $1-x$ instead of $x$ and  $x+1$, then $f$ is discontinuous everywhere and $f\circ f$ is the identity.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Nice variation, since it gives a compositional inverse pair of maps with each everywhere discontinuous.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Does this work if we make $f(x)=-x$ if $x$ algebraic and $1-x$ if $x$ transcendental?

Answer (score 7):

$$f(x) =\left\lbrace \begin{array}{ll}
x & \text{ if } x\not\in\lbrace 0,1\rbrace \\
1 & \text{ if } x=0 \\
0 & \text{ if } x=1
\end{array}  \right.$$
for example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In fact, one can construct a *maximally disconnected function* in the sense that it is discontinuous on every open interval $(a, b)$.

This is constructed by having every open interval $(a, b)$ map to $\mathbb{R}$. An example of this is [Conway's base 13 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function)

Another example is the indicator function for rational numbers.

Define a function

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} x \in \mathbb{Q} & 1 \\x \notin \mathbb{Q} & 0\end{cases}
$$

This function is discontinuous everywhere because the rationals are dense in the reals, and so are the irrationals.

Comment: Is the indicator function a bijection?

Comment: No, but $g(x) = (-1)^{f(x)}\cdot x$ is a discontinuous bijection, the identity on the irrationals and $-x$ on the rationals

Comment: Also if in the first one every open interval maps to $\mathbb{R},$ it won't be a bijection, at least if these maps are each onto.

Comment: @CarlMummert The version you have would be continuous at $0.$ But that could probably easily be adjusted for.