# Prove or Disprove: There exists $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is onto and one-to-one but not continuous.

Tags: calculus

There exists $f:  \mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ that is onto and one-to-one but not continuous.

I believe this statement is wrong, because values exist in the function's image that will not be "used" due to the function not being continuous. And since the function is one to one, no other number in the domain will be able to use up that specific y value in the range/image.

Am I correct? What could I use for a more concrete proof?

Comment: Duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1780909/339790

Answer (score 3):

Take $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x) = x$ if $x$ is rational, and $f(x) = - x$ if $x$ is irrational. This is one-to-one and onto but continuous nowhere (except at $x = 0$).

Comment: So this proves the statement is correct. Is there a concrete way to prove that the statement is true though ?

Comment: @RonaldB: An example is a concrete proof.